# Creating Nested `column` in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if it's possible to make nested columns or some other way to make this layout happen.

https://github.com/BadCo55/POS-TEST.git

This is how I attempted to make it happen, with a `div` inside of the `div`.. What I'm looking for is 'Column 4' to be on the right side of "Column 3' on the same line.

Here is a photo with a bit of a better description of the layout I'm looking for:

[image: Design Layout]

Comment: Have you tried using CSS Grid?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do so. You could look up for float, flex or grid layout.
Since you posted some code with flexbox I did the same.

Here is a proposition of mine to reproduce your attached screenshot :

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* This section is the grid method */

.Grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: calc(100% + 30px);
    margin: calc(30px / -2);
}

.Grid__Item {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    margin: calc(30px / 2);
}

/* Modifiers */
.Grid__Item--oneWhole {
    width : 100%;
}

.Grid__Item--oneHalf {
    width : calc(100% / 2 - 30px);
}

/* This styles the content */

.Content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding : 30px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    margin : 10px;
    font-size : 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* This styles the borders */

.Border {
    border : solid 1px black;
}

.Border--red {
    border-color: red;
}

.Border--orange {
    border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1><span>Diversified </span>Home Inspections</h1>

        <div class="Grid">
            <!-- Column - 50% width -->
            <div class="Grid__Item Grid__Item--oneHalf Border Border--red">

                <!-- We add another grid to split our layout one more time -->
                <div class="Grid">

                    <!-- Column - 100% width (next ones will go below) -->
                    <div class="Grid__Item Grid__Item--oneWhole Border Border--orange">
                        <div class="Content Border Border--orange">
                            <span>Content 1</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Column - 50% width -->
                    <div class="Grid__Item Grid__Item--oneHalf Border Border--orange">
                        <div class="Grid">
                            <div class="Grid__Item Grid__Item--oneWhole">
                                <div class="Content Border Border--orange">
                                    <span>Content 2_1</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="Grid__Item Grid__Item--oneWhole">
                                <div class="Content Border Border--orange">
                                    <span>Content 2_2</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Column - 50% width -->
                    <div class="Grid__Item Grid__Item--oneHalf Border Border--orange">
                        <div class="Grid">
                            <div class="Grid__Item Grid__Item--oneWhole">
                                <div class="Content Border Border--orange">
                                    <span>Content 3_1</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="Grid__Item Grid__Item--oneWhole">
                                <div class="Content Border Border--orange">
                                    <span>Content 4_1</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Column - 50% width -->
            <div class="Grid__Item Grid__Item--oneHalf Border Border--red">
                <div class="Content Border Border--orange">
                    <span>Content 4</span>
                </div>
                <div class="Content">
                    <button>Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```